# non constant harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

If $u$ is harmonic function on disk with radius $R$ around the origion, and non constant in it.

why is it true that $u$ cannot be constant in any sub-Disk (i.e disk with radius less than $R$)

thanks

Comment: Do you know how to represent a harmonic function on a disk as a Poisson integral? Do you now the maximum principle for harmonc harmonics? What kinds of things have you studied so far.

Answer (score 0):

Because than $u$ is equal to a constant function on an open set (the sub disk) which implies by the [identity theorem for harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) that $u$ is constant on the disk with radius $R$.

Comment: I am not familiar with complex analysis yet. is it possible without this Thm?

Comment: It's harmonic function, so it has to do something with complex analysis..

Comment: Well now, people certainly study harmonic functions in for example $R^n$, which can't have anything to do with complex analysis. Of course complex analysis often does give the simplest approach when $n=2$.